Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the roots of an quadratic equation $x^2+px+q=0$ and gamma and $\delta$ be the root of $x^2+Px+Q=0$. Express ....
Question: Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the roots of an equation $x^2+px+q=0$
and let $\gamma$ and $\delta$ be the roots of  $x^2+Px +Q=0$
Express $(\alpha - \gamma)(\beta - \gamma)(\alpha - \delta)(\beta - \delta)$ in terms of the coefficient $p,q,P$ and $Q$
This is what i have tried: So I know that alpha and beta are the roots so they can be found using the quadratic formula $\implies$ $\alpha= \dfrac{-p + \sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}$, and
$\beta= \dfrac{-p-\sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}$ and i did the same for the other equation and replaced these values for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and $\delta$ but the equation became too complex to calculate and I think it might not be helpful to solve this equation.
So I tried another approach: Here I used the Vieta's formula and I got that $\alpha + \beta=-p$ and $\alpha\beta=q$
[In the next relation  changed P for b and Q for c so the equation $x^2 +Px+Q$ became $x^2 +bx + c$ I did this because it was hard to me to spot the difference between P and p]
$\gamma+ \delta = -b$ and $\gamma \delta= c$ then I expanded the expression $(\alpha - \gamma)(\beta - \gamma)(\alpha - \delta)(\beta - \delta)$ but i couldn't sove it this way as well. Please help
Source: Challenge and Thrills of Pre-College Mathematics

You could've shortened your attempt by using the factor theorem.

I think there is no shortcut to expanding. You can try by writing the given expression as $(\gamma^2+p\gamma+q)(\delta^2+p\delta+q)$, then use the relations for $\gamma$ and $\delta$ obtained from Vieta's formulae to simplify the terms obtained.

You are using $p$ and $P$ as different variables, such as $q$ and $Q$. This can easily create confusion. If you really want to use similar names, you can opt for $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Let $f(x)=x^2+px+q=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ and $g(x)=x^2+Px+Q=(x-\gamma)(x-\delta)$.  Then the expression you are looking for is $f(\gamma)f(\delta)=g(\alpha)g(\beta)$, and expanding out either one will yield a solution.  We will expand out the one on the right.
$g(\alpha)g(\beta)=(\alpha^2+P\alpha+Q)(\beta^2+P\beta+Q)$ which expands out to $$\alpha^2\beta^2+P\alpha^2\beta+P\alpha\beta^2+Q\alpha^2+Q\beta^2+P^2\alpha\beta+PQ\alpha+PQ\beta+Q^2.$$  Combining certain terms, and grouping together factors of $\alpha\beta=q$ so that we can make use of Vieta's formulas, this simplifies to
$$(\alpha\beta)^2+P(\alpha\beta)(\alpha+\beta)+Q(\alpha^2+\beta^2)+P^2(\alpha\beta)+PQ(\alpha+\beta)+Q^2$$
Using the fact that $\alpha^2+\beta^2=(\alpha+\beta)^2-2\alpha\beta$, that $\alpha+\beta=-p$, and $\alpha\beta=q$, this simplifies to
$$q^2-Ppq+Q(p^2-2q)+P^2q-PQp+Q^2.$$
We can write this in a slightly more symmetric way, which emphasizes how $f(\gamma)f(\delta)=g(\alpha)g(\beta)$.  Namely
$$(q^2+Q^2)-(Pp)(q+Q)+(p^2Q+P^2q)-2qQ,$$
which makes it easier to see the symmetry if we swap $p$ with $P$ and $q$ with $Q$.

We remark that this is a polynomial in the coefficients of the polynomials that vanishes if the two polynomials share a root, and can be expressed more generally as the resultant of the two polynomials.

Can you please tell me how did you come up with this like what made you think to do it this way and like how do I think about such a long proof in my head ?

For the resultant of two quadratic polynomials see this answer.

@HARSHKUMAR There were a few motivators.  First, since the polynomial you had was preserved by swapping $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we knew it could be written in terms of $p$ and $q$, and because it was preserved by swapping $\delta$ and $\gamma$ it could be written in terms of $P$ and $Q$.  Recognizing it as $f(\delta)f(\gamma)$ is just experience working with factored forms of polynomials, and saved some time but was not strictly necessary.  The rest is just looking at how to apply the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials to write symmetric polynomials in terms of elementary ones.
